# How long was Montague in limbo?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Fred and George push Montague into the vanishing cabinet and he is stuck in limbo since the path between the cabinets is broken. Is it mentioned how long he is stuck there before apparating out of there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Montague escaped the Vanishing Cabinet the very next day.**

(All quotes are from Chapter Twenty-Eight of *Order of the Phoenix*.)

He was initially forced into the cabinet during the morning break:

> “Yeah, Montague tried to do us during break,” said George.
>
> “What do you mean, ‘tried’?” said Ron quickly.
>
> “He never managed to get all the words out,” said Fred, “due to the fact that we forced him headfirst into that Vanishing Cabinet on the first floor.”

This conversation occurred just before lunch:

> “You don’t get it, Hermione, do you?” said Fred, smiling at her. “We don’t care about staying anymore. We’d walk out right now if we weren’t determined to do our bit for Dumbledore first. So anyway,” he checked his watch, “phase one is about to begin. I’d get in the Great Hall for lunch if I were you, that way the teachers will see you can’t have had anything to do with it.”

On the way to the Great Hall, Harry is stopped by Filch who takes him to Umbridge:

> “Yeah, all right,” said Ron, and the three of them moved toward the doors to the Great Hall, but Harry had barely glimpsed today’s ceiling of scudding white clouds when somebody tapped him on the shoulder and, turning, he found himself almost nose to nose with Filch, the caretaker. He took several hasty steps backward; Filch was best viewed at a distance.
>
> “The headmistress would like to see you, Potter,” he leered.

The meeting is interrupted by the Weasley twins setting off fireworks:

> “Back to lunch with you, Potter!” cried Umbridge, raising her wand and dashing out of the office. Harry gave her a few seconds’ start then hurried after her to see what the source of all the uproar was.

That night Hermione congratulated Fred and George:

> Fred and George were heroes that night in the Gryffindor common room. Even Hermione fought her way through the excited crowd around them to congratulate them.

When Harry went to sleep that night he had one of his recurring dreams about the Department of Mysteries, and was awakened by some of the remaining fireworks, and noted that he had Occlumency with Snape the next evening:

> Glittering, pink-and-silver winged piglets were now soaring past the windows of Gryffindor Tower. Harry lay and listened to the appreciative whoops of Gryffindors in the dormitories below them. His stomach gave a sickening jolt as he remembered that he had Occlumency the following evening....

He then spends the next day worrying about the Occlumency lesson:

> Harry spent the whole of the next day dreading what Snape was going to say if he found out how much farther into the Department of Mysteries he had penetrated during his last dream.

That evening he indeed goes to Snape’s office:

> Resigned to the worst, he set off for Snape’s office after dinner.

The lesson with Snape is interrupted by Malfoy announcing that Montague had been found:

> “It’s Professor Umbridge, sir — she needs your help,” said Malfoy. “They’ve found Montague, sir. He’s turned up jammed inside a toilet on the fourth floor.”
>
> “How did he get in there?” demanded Snape.
>
> “I don’t know, sir, he’s a bit confused...”
>
> “Very well, very well — Potter,” said Snape, “we shall resume this lesson tomorrow evening instead.”

Thus, Montague was forced into the cabinet in the morning (during a break sometime before lunch) and was found the next evening.

Comment: Excellently researched.

Comment: I'd just like to point out (I'm sure others have before me) that due to Hogwarts not allowing apparation inside its territory, Montague somehow would have had to bypass the strong Hogwarts magic to be able to apparate into Hogwarts again. His ability to do that could have been a literal breakthrough for Voldemort and crew in the next books